# R packages to calculate Effect Size

Tags: r, t-test, effect-size, statistical-power

There are several R packages with functionality to calculate effect size. Recently I start to use the package `pwr`. Taking `pwr.t.test` for example (within the context of two sample t-test), [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwr/pwr.pdf) it says once sample size, significance level and power are specified, effect size will be determined.

I have two questions:

1. What kind of the effect size does `pwr.t.test` return?
2. As far as I know, Cohen's d is one type of effect size. It is calculated purely by difference of means and standard deviation of the two samples. If `pwr.t.test` returns Cohen's d or similar metrics, why do we need to specify power and significance level?

Correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

`pwr.t.test` does not calculate effect size at all, but [statistical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power). The package is called "pwr" because it is meant for **p**o**w**e**r** analysis. From that package, `cohen.ES` can compute effect sizes.

Comment: What you wrote is correct and helpful, however this length of your answer is very short. We can either convert it to a comment or you can extend it, e.g. with an example.

Comment: @Ferdi I don't have the reputation to comment, so I posted my comment as an answer. If you can, you are welcome to convert it to a comment.

Comment: For posterity: This answer is incorrect, pwr.t.test does compute effect size (from the documentation):

"Exactly one of the parameters ’d’,’n’,’power’ and ’sig.level’ must be passed as NULL, and that parameter is determined from the others [d is the effect size]. Notice that the last one has non-NULL default so NULL must be explicitly passed if you want to compute it."

If you pass values for all but 'd', you'll get the effect size.